# Computer crashes on startup of 3D rendering games

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, crash, gaming

My computer renders games similar to Minecraft just fine, but games with more intensive graphics like:

- Planetside 2
- Tom Clancy's Ghosts Recon Phantoms

it crashes the instant it needs to render something. Games which also render 3D like Minecraft give no problems. I've tried the following steps:

- disabling anti-virus, **Kaspersky**,
- updating the drivers
- Checking that my computer is not overheating.

One strange thing which occurs is when I play Unturned. When I exit the window and open another tab, and return to Unturned, the screen freezes for about 2 seconds and then the computer crashes.

```
OS:       Windows 7

Graphics: GeForce GTX 650

RAM:      8 GB
```

Comment: Are your drivers up to date? Has it worked before?

Comment: I have tried updating all the drivers I could think of, yes.

Comment: Converted the above to a comment. In case the OP ends up with yet another account... @christoffellis probably should *register* an account, then use the contact us link to merge all of his accounts together.

Comment: Allright, all fixed, any suggestions for a fix?